# Extract all the users in all the local groups in windows server

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have to find all the users in all the local groups via batch script and should redirect to an output file.

I can extract for one group and redirect to a file.

```
net localgroup "Administrators" > c:\temp.txt
```

But i have to get for the list of users for all the groups that is displayed for the below command.

```
net localgroup
```

Comment: Use a `FOR /F` command to capture the output from the `NET LOCALGROUP` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually running only `net localgroup` returns the groups with a starting asterisk `*` So this should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('net localgroup') do (
  set "var=%%a"
  set var=!var:~1!
  net localgroup "!var!" >> someoutput.txt
)
```

**Edit**

as per your comment, we can simply check if the files created has the correct number of lines, if not, delete it.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('net localgroup') do (
   set "var=%%a"
   set var=!var:~1!
   net localgroup "!var!" > "!var!.txt"
  for /f %%i in ('type "!var!.txt" ^|find "" /v /c ') do set /a count=%%i
   if !count! lss 10 del /Q "!var!.txt"
 )
```

Comment: You can use the `FOR` variable directly if you use `tokens=* delims=*`.

Comment: I edited the script to create separate files by mentioning "!var!" in output file name. I need to further refine it not to create files if there are no members in it. Will you be able to help here?